# How do I get a list of column name using Linq to Sql

Tags: linq-to-sql

How can i dynamically get a list of Column names based on my query model below using Linq to SQL. Example of query below.

```
public void GetColumnName()
{
       var db = from ci in Db.CatalogItems
                join i in Items
                on ci.ItemId equals i.ItemId
                select i;
}
```

---

I'm new to the concept of Reflection. How do I go about doing that with the model query above?

Answer (score 0):

use reflection on db? (get the fields)

Answer (score 0):

```
from rec in Db.syscolumns ....
```